# JUnit 5 fails to find Tests from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, junit5

Similar stackoverflow posting: "JUnit 5 ConsoleLauncher doesn't work" answered Marc Philipp 13 March 2018.

I tried to duplicate the example posted in the above posting. The JUnit Test class is "DisplayNameDemo.java" shown below:

```
DisplayNameDemo.java

   import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

   import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

   @DisplayName("A special test case")
   public class DisplayNameDemo {
 
      @Test
      @DisplayName("Custom test name containing spaces")
      void testWithDisplayNameContainingSpaces() {
      }

      @Test
      @DisplayName("╯°□°）╯")
      void testWithDisplayNameContainingSpecialCharacters() {
      }

      @Test
      @DisplayName(" ")
      void testWithDisplayNameContainingEmoji() {
      }
  }
```

Here is my JUnit 5 command line command:
"java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar --classpath . --select-class            DisplayNameDemo --include-classname '.*'"

This failed when I executed it, but passed when executed in the post.  Here a partial of my failed result:

```
~/junit5.6.2/console$ java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar --classpath .    --select-class DisplayNameDemo --include-classname '.*'

Thanks for using JUnit! Support its development at https://junit.org/sponsoring

Usage: ConsoleLauncher [-h] [--disable-ansi-colors] [--disable-banner]
                   [--fail-if-no-tests] [--scan-modules] [--scan-classpath[=PATH[;|:
                   PATH...]]]... [--details=MODE] [--details-theme=THEME]
                   [--reports-dir=DIR] [-c=CLASS]... [--config=KEY=VALUE]... [-cp=PATH
```

I have all classes in the same directory as the junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar file. I also have my classpath set to the local directory "." as shown above.

I cannot understand why this example fails.  I would very much appreciate some help - especially from Marc Philipp or Sormuras on stackoverflow.  Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't point with `--classpath` to your compiled Java classes (where the `.class` files are), but to your *raw* `.java` files.

If you are using Maven to build your project, your compiled test classes are inside `target/test-classes`. You can now use the standalone console launcher from the root of your project like:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar --class-path 'target/test-classes' -c your.package.YourTest
```

If you are not using Maven and want to still run it with the console launcher with `--class-path .` then make sure your `.class` files are there. E.g. use `javac MyJavaTest.java` to compile them (a little bit cumbersome without Maven/Gradle as you would have to include all your libraries to the compile step).

For more information and practical examples, consider [following this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/junit5/junit-5-consolelauncher-examples/).